# What is the memory "sweet spot" for Windows 7 virtual system?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

What is the minimum memory you would allocate to a Windows 7 virtual machine and have it run "reasonably well?"

Taking the advice from Scott Hanselman's: [VM Performance Checklist](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VMPerformanceChecklistBeforeYouComplainThatYourVirtualMachineIsSlow.aspx), I routinely *started* with 512 MB for WinXP installations and that seemed sufficient most of the time.

The Windows 7 VMs will be mostly used for routine software testing. No major resource requirements but I want it to be *usable*. What *minimum* memory setting would you choose for a basic installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 GB should be fine for regular use, if you plan to run some heavy-weights in your virtual machine, increase the memory.

*if you strip/tweak the heck out of 7 with vLite you may get away with 512 MB, but even then it may not run your application satisfactory.*

Answer (score 2):

I ran Windows 7 RC in a VM on my machine for a couple months. I had 1024MB of Ram dedicated. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Windows 7 VM set up for remote debugging and I have 786MB allocated. It's a bit slow to start but once it's up and running I have no issues working on it.